# Using dcast to compare 2 times and facet by variable

Tags: r

I am using the built-in "french_fries" data in package reshape2 to make a scatter plot comparing time = 1 to time = 10 and facet by each variable. So far I have the following code:

```
    molten_fries <- melt(french_fries, id=1:4)

    fry_dat <- molten_fries %>%
    filter(time==c(1,10))

    cast_fries <- dcast(fry_dat, rep + treatment + subject + variable~time,
    mean, value.var="value", na.rm=TRUE)
    colnames(cast_fries) <- c("rep", "treatment", "subject" , "variable",
    "t1","t10")

    ggplot(cast_fries, aes(t1,t10)) + 
    geom_point(na.rm=T) +
    facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one problem in your code : To select time 1 & 10, either you filter `time == 1 & time == 10` or `time %in% c(1,10)`. The rest is ok

```
library(reshape2)
molten_fries <- melt(french_fries, id=1:4)

library(dplyr)
fry_dat <- molten_fries %>%
  filter(time %in% c(1,10))

cast_fries <- dcast(fry_dat, rep + treatment + subject + variable~time,
                    mean, value.var="value", na.rm=TRUE)
colnames(cast_fries) <- c("rep", "treatment", "subject" , "variable",
                          "t1","t10")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cast_fries, aes(t1,t10)) + 
  geom_point(na.rm=T) +
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=1)
```

[image: ggplot_graph]

Comment: Thank you! I thought I was just casting it incorrectly, but it ended up being a filtering/selecting issue. Problem solved.